# how to connect a .net application to database using service account

Tags: sql, .net, database-connection, service-accounts

How to connect the .net application to the database using service account, my application currently has a connection string which is directly connected to the database.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

add below tag into your web.config file -
`<identity impersonate="true" />`
`<authentication mode="Windows" />`

create AD group and add group name into app setting -
`<add key="as you preferred" value="AD Group name" />`

authenticate on login, set Identity of your application pool to that specific user.